# Unable to handle remote control events for backgronud audio

Tags: ios, audio, background

In the view controller for my audio player I've added this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

This switches the icon in the player controls from the iPod icon to my own app, it also puts the little playback icon in the status bar.

Next I added this to my view controller to handle the remote events:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"REMOTE EVENT!");
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [streamer start];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            [streamer stop];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However, this is never called. I tried bringing up the playback controls while the app was running, I tried going back to my home screen and tapping some playback controls, and I tried my earbuds' controls. All had no luck.

Does anyone have any pointers as to where I can be going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have implemented the wrong method: instead of - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated it should have been - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before and discovered that in my problem it was because my view was a subview and the parent was catching the remote events. I would start in the AppDelegate and implement the method and see if anything is being sent to the AppDelegate and then trace it down from there. Chances are there is a view or viewController that is catching the event and not passing it along.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for quite a while. Can you give me details about how to debug like you did?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to set your audio session? Use AVAudioSession and set the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback before becoming first responder.